# Hibernate OGM with mongodb in an enterprise solution

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm, nosql

I wanted to ask you, if you have any experience that `Hibernate OGM` works as much fine with `mongodb`, that it could be used in an enterprise solution without any worries. With other words - does this combination work as fine as for example `Hibernate ORM` with `MySQL` and is is also that easy to set up? Is it worth to use it - meant the level of afford needed to set it up compared to the level of improvement of the work with the database? Would you prefer another OGM framework or even don't use any? I read about it some time ago, but it was in the early stages of this project and didn't work too well yet. Thanks for advices and experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the Hibernate OGM authors)

> With other words - does this combination work as fine as for example Hibernate ORM with MySQL?

The 4.1 release is the first final we consider to be ready to use in production. The general user experience should be not much different from using the classic Hibernate ORM (which still is what you use under the hood when using Hibernate OGM). Also the MongoDB dialect probably is the one we put most effort in, so it is in good shape.

But as Hibernate OGM is a fairly young project, of course there may be bugs and glitches which need to be ironed out. Feature-wise, there are some things not supported yet (e.g. secondary tables, criteria API, more complex JPA queries), but you either shouldn't really need those in most kinds of applications or there are work-arounds (e.g. native queries).

> and is is also that easy to set up?

Yes, absolutely. The set-up is not different from using Hibernate ORM / JPA with an RDBMS. You only use another JPA provider class (`HibernateOgmPersistence`) and need to set some OGM-specific options (which NoSQL store to use, host name etc.). Check out [this blog post](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/NoSQLWithHibernateOGM101PersistingYourFirstEntities) which walks you through the set-up. For store-specific settings (e.g. how to store associations in document stores) there is an easy-to-use option system based on annotations and/or a fluent API.

> [Is it worth the effort] to set it up compared to the level of improvement of the work with the database?

I don't think there is a general answer to that. In many cases object mappers like Hibernate ORM/OGM are great, in others cases working with plain SQL or NoSQL APIs might be a better option. It depends on your use case and its specific requirements. In general, OxMs work well if there is a defined domain model which you want to persist, navigate its associations etc.

> Would you prefer another OGM framework

I'm obviously biased, but let me say that using Hibernate OGM allows you to

- benefit from the eco-system existing around JPA/Hibernate, be it integration with other libraries such as Hibernate Validator or Hibernate Search (or your in-house developed Hibernate-based API) or tooling such as modelling tools which emit JPA entities.
- work with different NoSQL backends using the same API. So if chances are you need to integrate another NoSQL store (e.g. Neo4j to run graph queries) or an RDMBS, then Hibernate OGM will allow you to do so easily.

> I read about it some time ago, but it was in the early stages of this project

Much work has been put into Hibernate OGM over the last year, so my recommendation definitely is to try it out and see in a prototype or spike how it works for your requirements.

If you have any feature requests or questions, please let us know and we'll see what we can do for you.

Comment: Thank you Gunnar for an exhausting answer! I'll definitely bring this topic to discussion ! :)